Flashing/flickering submenu in tactile events simulation - onPointerEnter - React
Submenu flashing/flickering when I click with tactile events simulation active in browser inspector (appear at the click then disappear immediately).
However, I have no problem when hovering both on firefox and on chrome.
My question is :
How I can let submenu display after the first touch of a mobile user then disappear it after the second touch ?
I tried to replace onPointerEnter by onPointerOver but inconvincing, or by onPointerDown but "hover" and "click" events conflict and cause bugs. 
Unless there is a way to distinguish "hover" and "click" pointer event.
I also tried by setting stopPropagation() and preventDefault() in onPointerEnter of sub-menu component with not success (see third code block).
My research led me to see releasePointerCapture (on this thread) but I thought it is not suited my case.
Code of menu (highest component) :
export default function Menu({checkboxIsChecked}) { // boolean parameter to open/hide menu on mobile
const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

  function handleDisplayOfSubMenu() {
    if (!isOpen) {
       setOpen(true);
    } else if (isOpen) {
      setOpen(false);
    }
  }
  return (
    <ul className={`${checkboxIsChecked ? "right-0" : "-right-full"} absolute bg-primary top-0 w-3/6 pt-28 h-screen text-end duration-300 md:flex md:items-center md:w-auto md:static md:h-auto md:pt-0`}>
      { {/* generates li for an array element */}
        [...Array(navbarItems.length)].map((e, i) => (
          <MenuItems
             menuItem={navbarItems[i]} onHover={handleDisplayOfSubMenu} menuState={isOpen}
          />
        ))
      }
     </ul>
    )
}

Code of menu item :
function MenuItems({menuItem, onHover, menuState}) {

    if (menuItem.hasSubMenu) {
        return (
            <SubMenuItem menuItem={menuItem} handleHoveringOfMenuItems={onHover} menuState={menuState}/>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <li key={menuItem.key}>
                <Link href={menuItem.link} className={menuItemsClasses}>{menuItem.title}</Link>
            </li>
        );
    }
}

Code of sub-menu item (lowest component) :
function SubMenuItem({menuItem, handleHoveringOfMenuItems, menuState}) {
  return <>
    <li
      onPointerEnter={ (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        handleHoveringOfMenuItems();
      }}
      onPointerLeave={ () => {
        handleHoveringOfMenuItems()
      }}
    >
    </li>
  </>;
}

